# Using jest with TypeScript I get "TypeError: The "type" argument must be specified"

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

This is the line of code it's failing on:

```js
const erc20BalanceChangeEvent: Event<BalanceChange> = new Event<BalanceChange>()
```

I don't understand what it means as the type for the variable is clearly there. Googling that error comes back with no results.

[image]

I'm at a complete loss as to what to do. All help appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide more context?  Where is Event defined?  Which API?

Comment: Event is my own class. Thanks for your comment though, the auto importer in vscode went weird and didn't import anything but Ctrl + Click was taking me to the correct implementation. Anyway manually adding the import statements fixed this.

Comment: The autoimport didn't work because `Event` is a generic name, which might be conflicting with a global Event namespace. You may rename your type to something more specific to your use-case to avoid issues like this in future

Comment: Thanks I'll update it.